Fill a matrix with randomly placed elements that are a certain distance apart
Problem statement
I want to populate a matrix of points with randomly placed elements, here denoted as x. In all matrix rows there must be an equal number of x-elements with
at least d points between them.
Partial solution
Matrix rows and columns
n = 15;

Matrix of points
m = Array["." &, {n, n}];

Minimum points between elements (distance)
d = 2;

Possible positions
p = Range[1, n, d + 1]


{1, 4, 7, 10, 13}

Number of elements per row
e = 3;

x - Positions
xp =
 Catenate @ Table[
   Map[
    Prepend[i] @* List,
    RandomSample[p, e] + RandomInteger[{0, 2}]],
   {i, 1, n}];

Possible result with d = 2 and e = 3
MapAt[Style["x", Red, Bold] &, xp] @ m // MatrixForm


Possible results with d = 2 and e = 2 / e = 5

Question
Because of the addition of RandomInteger[{0, 2}] my solution only functions with row lengths n which are divisible by 3. How can I implement these random placements
(a) for arbitrary matrix sizes n?
(b) for arbitrary distances d?

If you really want to sample randomly (and uniformly), I believe you should first construct the set of all possible rows (or ensure the uniformness in some other way).
Here is an approach using IntegerPartitions.
randomMatrix[n_, d_, e_] := 
 Module[{allPartitions, allowedPartitions, allRows},
  (* Construct all partitions of a row into e+1 chunks of . *)
  allPartitions = Catenate[Permutations /@ 
      IntegerPartitions[n - e, {e + 1}, Range[0, n]]];

  (* Select partitions where length of all inner chunks is at least d *)
  allowedPartitions = Cases[allPartitions, {_, x___, _} /; x >= d];

  (* Transform partitions into rows of x and . *)
  allRows = Table[Flatten@Riffle[ConstantArray[".", #] & /@ part, 
      Style["x", Red, Bold]], {part, allowedPartitions}];

  (* Sample randomly *)
  RandomChoice[allRows, n]
  ]

randomMatrix[10, 2, 3] // MatrixForm



Using a RelationGraph projection:
 matrixRowElementsByDistance[n_, e_, d_] := Module[{graph, paths},
  graph = RelationGraph[#2 - #1 >= d + 1 &, Range[n]];
  paths = Flatten[Table[FindPath[graph, i, j, {e - 1}, All]
     , {i, VertexList[graph]}, {j, VertexList[graph]}], 2] ;
  MapAt[Style["x", Red, Bold] & , Array["." &, {n, n}]
     , Flatten[
         MapIndexed[
           Tuples[{#2, #1}] &, Check[RandomChoice[paths, n], {}]],1]]      
 ]

 matrixRowElementsByDistance[50, 10, 3] // 
    MatrixPlot[#, ColorRules -> {"." -> White, _ -> Red}, Mesh -> True] &


